# OpenCL: work group concept

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

I don't really understand the purpose of Work-Groups in OpenCL.

I understand that they are a group of Work Items (supposedly, hardware threads), which ones get executed in parallel.

However, why is there this need of coarser subdivision ? Wouldn't it be OK to have only the grid of threads (and, *de facto*, only one W-G)?

Should a Work-Group exactly map to a physical core ? For example, the TESLA c1060 card is said to have 240 cores. How would the Work-Groups map to this??

Also, as far as I understand, work-items inside a work group can be synchronized thanks to memory fences. Can work-groups synchronize or is that even needed ? Do they talk to each other via shared memory or is this only for work items (not sure on this one)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Part of the confusion here I think comes down to terminology. What GPU people often call cores, aren't really, and what GPU people often call threads are only in a certain sense.

**Cores**
A core, in GPU marketing terms may refer to something like a CPU core, or it may refer to a single lane of a SIMD unit - in effect a single core x86 CPU would be four cores of this simpler type. This is why GPU core counts can be so high. It isn't really a fair comparison, you have to divide by 16, 32 or a similar number to get a more directly comparable core count.

**Work-items**
Each work-item in OpenCL is a thread in terms of its control flow, and its memory model. The hardware may run multiple work-items on a single thread, and you can easily picture this by imagining four OpenCL work-items operating on the separate lanes of an SSE vector. It would simply be compiler trickery that achieves that, and on GPUs it tends to be a mixture of compiler trickery and hardware assistance. OpenCL 2.0 actually exposes this underlying hardware thread concept through sub-groups, so there is another level of hierarchy to deal with.

**Work-groups**
Each work-group contains a set of work-items that must be able to make progress in the presence of barriers. In practice this means that it is a set, all of whose state is able to exist at the same time, such that when a synchronization primitive is encountered there is little overhead in switching between them and there is a guarantee that the switch is possible.

A work-group must map to a single compute unit, which realistically means an entire work-group fits on a single entity that CPU people would call a core - CUDA would call it a multiprocessor (depending on the generation), AMD a compute unit and others have different names. This locality of execution leads to more efficient synchronization, but it also means that the set of work-items can have access to locally constructed memory units. They are expected to communicate frequently, or barriers wouldn't be used, and to make this communication efficient there may be local caches (similar to a CPU L1) or scratchpad memories (local memory in OpenCL).

As long as barriers are used, work-groups can synchronize internally, between work-items, using local memory, or by using global memory. Work-groups cannot synchronize with each other and the standard makes no guarantees on forward progress of work-groups relative to each other, which makes building portable locking and synchronization primitives effectively impossible.

A lot of this is due to history rather than design. GPU hardware has long been designed to construct vector threads and assign them to execution units in a fashion that optimally processes triangles. OpenCL falls out of generalising that hardware to be useful for other things, but not generalising it so much that it becomes inefficient to implement.

Answer (score 9):

There are already alot of good answers, for further understanding of the terminology of OpenCL [this paper](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Esmeyer/cuda/Preso07-OpenCL.pdf) (*"An Introduction to the OpenCL Programming Model"* by Jonathan Tompson and Kristofer Schlachter) actually describes all the concepts very well.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Link is fixed, thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 6):

One benefit of work groups is they enable using shared local memory as a programmer-defined cache. A value read from global memory can be stored in shared work-group local memory and then accessed quickly by any work item in the work group. A good example is the game of life: each cell depends on itself and the 8 around it. If each work item read this information you'd have 9x global memory reads. By using work groups and shared local memory you can approach 1x global memory reads (only approach since there is redundant reads at the edges).

Answer (score 5):

Use of the work-groups allows more optimization for the kernel compilers. This is because data is not transferred between work-groups. Depending on used OpenCL device, there might be caches that can be used for local variables to result faster data accesses. If there is only one work-group, local variables would be just the same as global variables which would lead to slower data accesses.

Also, usually OpenCL devices use Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) extensions to achieve good parallelism. One work group can be run in parallel with SIMD extensions.

```
 Should a Work-Group exactly map to a physical core ?
```

I think that, only way to find the fastest work-group size, is to try different work-group sizes. It is also possible to query the CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE from the device with [clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.html). The fastest size should be multiple of that.

```
 Can work-groups synchronize or is that even needed ?
```

Work-groups [cannot be synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895001/opencl-synchronization-between-work-groups). This way there is no data dependencies between them and they can also be run sequentially, if that is considered to be the fastest way to run them. To achieve same result, than synchronization between work-groups, kernel needs to split into multiple kernels. Variables can be transferred between the kernels with buffers.